# Is it possible to Combine querysets from different models into a single queryset or a list and order by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

models.py

```
    # Customer Model

class Customer(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    primary_contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    secondary_contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customers')
    

# Issue Model

class Issue(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    tt = models.CharField(default='SB', max_length=3)
    voucher = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=6)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    kt = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    discount = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    note = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=100)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)



    @property
    def kt_21(self):
        return round(self.kt / 21 * self.quantity , 2)
    
    @property
    def vat_amt(self):
        return (self.quantity * self.rate - self.discount) * self.vat/100
    

    # Total amount exclusive of VAT
    @property
    def tot_amount(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate
    
    
    # Total amount inclusive of VAT
    @property
    def total_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate + self.vat_amt
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('issue-hist')

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.customer) + " - "+ str(self.tot_amount)+' SAR'
    

# Receive Model

class Receive(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    tt = models.CharField(default='RB', max_length=3)
    voucher = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=6)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    kt = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    discount = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    note = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=100)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)

    @property
    def kt_21(self):
        return round(self.kt / 21 * self.quantity , 2)
    
    @property
    def vat_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate * self.vat/100
    
    @property
    def tot_amount(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate

    @property
    def total_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate + self.vat_amt
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rec-hist')

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.customer) + " - "+ str(self.tot_amount)+' SAR'


# Sales-Retrun Model

class SalesReturn(models.Model):

    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    tt = models.CharField(default='SRB', max_length=3)

    voucher = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=6)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    kt = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    discount = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    note = models.CharField(blank = True, default='', max_length=100)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)

    @property
    def kt_21(self):
        return round(self.kt / 21 * self.quantity , 2)
    
    @property
    def vat_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate * self.vat/100
    
    @property
    def tot_amount(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate

    @property
    def total_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate + self.vat_amt
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sr-hist')

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.customer) + " - "+ str(self.tot_amount)+' SAR'
```

I want to query all the receives, issues and returns for a particular customer, which I have achieved. But now I want the 3 querysets to be combined into a single queryset and order them by 'date_time'. I tried appending all of them to a list and sorting them but that didn't work, it did gave a sorted list but it did not sort them in date order, it sorted them in a manner where all issues, receives and returns were grouped together and ordered by date.

This is what I tried:

```
issues = list((Issue.objects.filter(customer = cust).order_by('-date_time'))
receives = list(Receive.objects.filter(customer = cust).order_by('-datetime')
   for issue in issues:
        x.append(issue)


    for rec in receives:
        x.append(rec)
```

I also tries using sort() but it keeps returning None

```
x.sort(key = lambda r: r.date_time)
```

Comment: Can you share the attempt you've made?

Comment: I added what I tried to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with four queries and then merge these in the same list:

```
from operator import attrgetter

klasses = [Issue, Receive, SalesReturn]
customer = None  # some customer
result = sorted(
    [
        m
        for klass in klasses
        for m in klass.objects.filter(customer=customer).order_by('date_time')
    ],
    key=attrgetter('date_time'),
)
```

The `.order_by('date_time')` clause is not required, but *Timsort* often performs better if the data is already partly ordered, so we can (slightly) boost the process.

> I also tries using `sort()` but it keeps returning `None`.

Sort *always* returns `None`: it does not return a sorted list, it modifies the order of the list, so after the `.sort()` call, `x` is sorted.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I tried attrgetter too, That is when it is grouping all the categories together and then ordering them

Comment: @pipinstalllogic: as specified at the bottom, `x.sort(..)` returns `None`, because it modifies `x`, it does not return a sorted (copy).

Comment: it worked, I really can't thank you enough. Also can you explain the m before the first for loop?

Comment: @pipinstalllogic: `m` is the model object, we thus concatenate the items of the three querysets in the same list.

Comment: thanks, will have to look deeper into that.